# Не могу установить расширение cryptopro для php

Tags: php, криптопро

Ставлю расширение под Ubuntu server 14x64

Есть инструкция на сайте:

http://cpdn.cryptopro.ru/default.asp?url=content/cades/plugin-installation.html

Для сборки расширения `libphpcades` требуется:

Установить пакеты `libboost-dev` и `php-dev` из репозитория пакетов (сделал)

Установить `КриптоПро CSP` версии 4.0 или выше (сделал)

Установить пакет `cprocsp-pki-2.0.0-cades.rpm` и `cprocsp-devel` из состава `КриптоПро ЭЦП SDK` !!!
 Вот тут затык, там только есть пакет `devel` а вот `cades` в архиве нет... что делать?
Поэтому дальше по инструкции не могу двигаться, не появились файлы для компиляции расширения.

Может кто-то ставил это расширение?
Нужно для проверки цифровых подписей.

Comment: .rpm - для ubuntu нужен deb пакет

Comment: ну а как я по твоему установил devel) я разобрался, пакет перекодировал. но вот не могу в архиве найти пакета cades

Comment: вобщем написал в поддержку пост. пытался позвонить, не консультируют по телефону

Comment: Вы под какую версию php собирали крипту? в итоге все получилось? у меня сыпится при компиляции so. не пойму что сделал не так(

Answer (score 0):

Поддержка ответила

Добрый день!

Расширение для php входит в состав КриптоПро ЭЦП https://www.cryptopro.ru/products/cades/downloads
Необходимо удалить devel пакет из дистрибутива CSP (котрорый у Вас стоит сейчас) и поставить тот, ссыклу на который я прислал.
Если Вы собираете расширение для php7, то исходники нужно предварительно патчить https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/products/cades/php7_support.patch.zip